# Error "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?" after upgrade Linux kernel

Tags: docker

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with docker v1.8.2. Docker works well before. Then I just upgraded my Linux kernel from 3.16 to 4.05 and now docker is broken.

#### docker images

```
simlw@sim-lw:~$ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

#### ps auxww | grep docker

```
simlw@sim-lw:~$ ps auxww | grep docker   
simlw    23085  0.0  0.0  15976  2276 pts/24   S+   13:12   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

#### sudo docker -d

```
simlw@sim-lw:~$ sudo docker -d
Warning: '-d' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
WARN[0000] please use 'docker daemon' instead.          
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "aufs" failed: driver not supported 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this? thanks in advance.

Pleae note I've already read [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404597/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-docker-d-running-on-this-host) and [Docker Daemon not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088989/docker-daemon-not-running), and both of them don't help me out.

Comment: what's the output of `service docker start`? `service docker status`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu dropped support for AUFS since its Kernel package version 3.18, because from that version OverlayFS is part of Linux Kernel. I think your docker daemon is trying to use AUFS driver because you have a `/var/lib/docker/aufs` folder. Anyway, you can force to use the correct storage driver using the `-s` or `--storage-driver=` option when running the docker daemon.

So first, to test that the daemon works with the OverlayFS storage driver, run the daemon in a terminal: `sudo docker daemon -s overlay`. Once you have tested it is working correctly, you can modify it permanently editing the file `/etc/default/docker`, adding the next line:

```
# Force OverlayFS for storage driver
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS -s overlay"
```

Comment: Modification of /etc/default/docker does not affect systemd systems :(

Comment: For systemd systems see "Runtime directory and storage driver" in  https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/ also.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from Debian Jessie to testing and I'm now using linux-image-4.2 and I encountered the same kind of issue with a missing aufs driver.

A quick fix is to delete the docker aufs folder. You might lose some data, so please do it with care!

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs

Answer (score 0):

If the docker daemon is already runing, or you could run the command with `root` successfully, you may need to to add your user id to docker group with:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <userid>
```

and then logout.
If you still get the same info, try:

```
sudo service docker restart
```